# capture changes made to object outside yield statement python

Tags: python, syntax

I need a pythonic way to allow for this to work

```
def generator():
    i=0
    yield(i)
    print(i)

for i in generator():
    i=2
##should print 2
```

How can I modify the provided Python code to ensure that it prints `2` instead of `1` when iterating over the generator? I need a more pythonic approach for this requirement, as I have specific constraints related to ensuring the object is placed in the correct database based on changed values that are both efficient (as my database stores related objects near each other) and difficult to modify from outside.

Comment: `i=2` will never be able to modify `i` inside `generator`, unless they're both referring to the same variable. So `global i` inside `generator`, so they're both dealing with the same global variable. Of course, that's horrific and hardly pythonic.

Comment: In your real case, is `i` a container and you want to change values in that container?

Comment: Why are you using a generator for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) class to allow better control over the state of the iterator through additional methods:

```
class SettableIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def set_value(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        value = self.i
        self.i += 1
        return value

iterator = SettableIterator()
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        iterator.set_value(2)
    elif i == 3:
        break
```

This outputs:

```
0
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` inside `generator` creates a new local variable. You need to refer to the global one, by using `global`:

```py
def generator():
    global i
    yield(i)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators let you send data back to them at the cost of loosing the ability to use for loops. Wrap a while in a try/except block and you can do

```
def generator():
    i=0
    i = (yield i)
    print(i)

gen = generator()
try:
    i = None
    while True:
        i = gen.send(i)
        i = 2
except StopIteration:
    pass
finally:
    gen.close()
    del gen
```

Comment: thank you , unfortunately i cannot mark multiple answers as correct , but for anyone looking any of these answers should work depending on use case